# Python change list elements in a for loop

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list of 5 elements `x=[a,b,c,d,e]` and I want to run a for loop that prints all lists where two of the entries are 1 less than the corresponding entries in the original list.

What is a simple way to do this in Python?  Thanks in advance.

Edit:  if `x=[4,5,6,7,8]` I want:

```
[3,4,6,7,8], [3,5,5,7,8], [3,5,6,6,8] etc.
```

Comment: So you would want `[a-1,b-1,c,d,e]`, `[a-1,b,c-1,d,e]`, `[a-1,b,c,d-1,e]` etc.?

Comment: question doesn't make any sense, what is the original list? Does list contain ascii-characters or numbers or what? Please post input and expected output.

Comment: @F.J Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: @F.J - I'm really impressed by your psychic abilities!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> lis = [0,1,2,3,4]
>>> for x,y in combinations(range(len(lis)),2):
    l = lis[:]
    l[x] -= 1
    l[y] -= 1
    print l
...     
[-1, 0, 2, 3, 4]
[-1, 1, 1, 3, 4]
[-1, 1, 2, 2, 4]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
[0, 0, 1, 3, 4]
[0, 0, 2, 2, 4]
[0, 0, 2, 3, 3]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 4]
[0, 1, 1, 3, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

Shorter version:

```
for x,y in combinations(range(len(lis)),2):
    print [item - 1 if i in (x,y) else item  for i,item in enumerate(lis)]
...     
[-1, 0, 2, 3, 4]
[-1, 1, 1, 3, 4]
[-1, 1, 2, 2, 4]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 3]
[0, 0, 1, 3, 4]
[0, 0, 2, 2, 4]
[0, 0, 2, 3, 3]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 4]
[0, 1, 1, 3, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import combinations
a = [1,2,3,4]
for combination in combinations(range(len(a)),r=2):
    print [c-(1 if i in combination else 0) for i,c in enumerate(a)]
```